# Linux: what creates large hidden files at / at each startup?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

ALT Linux p8 (Mandriva based distro) with kernel 4.19 and systemd.
At each startup there is a new hidden file (starting with .) at / approx. 40-50 Mb:

```
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root     2048 мар 12 13:57 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root     2048 мар 12 13:57 ..
-rw-------   1 root root 45531136 мар 12 12:24 .16726
-rw-------   1 root root 50364416 мар 12 12:24 .894
-rw-------   1 root root 52592640 мар 12 13:57 .963
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 мар 11 20:15 bin
drwx------   5 root root     2048 мар 12 13:59 boot
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root     4340 мар 12 14:11 dev
drwxr-xr-x 149 root root     6144 мар 12 14:09 etc
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root     4096 дек 12  2019 home
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root     4096 мар 11 16:32 lib
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root     8192 мар 12 14:09 lib64
drwx------   2 root root     2048 дек 12  2019 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     2048 апр 12  2019 media
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root     2048 мар 29  2020 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     2048 фев 11  2016 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 296 root root        0 мар 12 16:57 proc
drwx------  12 root root     2048 мар 12 14:11 root
drwxr-xr-x  35 root root     1100 мар 12 14:57 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     6144 мар 12 14:09 sbin
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root     2048 фев 11  2016 selinux
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     2048 фев 11  2016 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root        0 мар 12 18:05 sys
drwxrwxrwt  15 root root     2048 мар 12 17:39 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root     2048 апр  5  2019 usr
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root     2048 ноя 14  2019 var
```

Files .16726, .894 and .963 after 3 reboot. ELF format. Looks like some RAM image of kernel space.

Can anyone tell what creates these files and how to turn it off?

P.S. Cannot attach systemctl list due to "This looks like spam" restriction.

**UPD 1**
Found out that these files are coredumps, created if some process crashed. Coredumps are turned off by default in almost all linux distributives (same is mine), but in some cases dumps can still be created by some processes (SDDM in my case). Solutions are:

1. update (or downgrade) the crashing process packet
2. of no result - try to disable special cases of dumps.

Currently stuck with second solution, as no upgrade available, and downgrade is impossible. Basic coredump can be disabled via /etc/sysctl/conf, /etc/systemd/, /etc/security/limits - lots! All these settings are set in my distro, trying  to find some more...

As an option, *sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=DIR* can be changed to some other than '/' unwritable directory (broken symlink, etc).

Comment: As this is not about programming, please ask at http://unix.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Try inspecting them some more. "ELF format" - are there any section? Headers? Comments? The files are created at startup - inspect each and every startup script, one at a time. How is initrd generated on your distribution? Research it (`mkinitcpio` or `mkinitrd` or similar), find the scripts that are added to initrd, inspect every one of them. Ask the question to "ALT Linux p8" maintaners - maybe it's expected. And maybe it's a filesystem error - inspect `dmesg` and logs.

Comment: Try using the `lsof` command to see which processes (if any) have the files open.

Comment: Is this system exposed to the internet?

Comment: @KamilCuk inspecting everything, of course, will solve the problem)) But i'm asking this question to receive really useful answer.

Comment: @IanAbbott files are created at system startup, and no one use them after (no process keeps them open).

Comment: @NateEldredge ok, i'll try.

Comment: @stark it's just a simple workstation (with interner access of course).

Comment: @Sash well, I believe people write on this forum, because they are "stuck" and don't know what to research further. Assuming that "inspecting everything, of course, will solve the problem", well, then that looks like the perfect way to pursue to solve the problem. I wanted to write some directions that you may inspect, that may indeed help to solve the problem, that's the intention indeed. So did you inspect them? It's not like such files are created on other computers, so there something specific to your station that creates them, so I do not believe there will be a universal answer.